# Changing function return value in C++ (In runtime)

Tags: c++, dll, hook

i want to change the return value of an external function (in runtime) which is inside another dll which gets loaded when the program starts.

Pratical example of what i want to do:

Function inside the dll:

```cpp
int numberOfMoney() {
   return 0;
}
```

My main program:

```cpp
    HMODULE handle = LoadLibraryA("/myDll.dll");

    auto gotFunc = GetProcAddress(handle, "numberOfMoney");
    // making numberOfMoney returning 1000 ???
```

Does anyone knows how could i do it? Maybe without external libraries? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to call the function if all it does is return a value that you’re going to ignore? Just write your own function that returns the value that you want. If there’s actually a reason to call hat function, write a function that calls it and massages the return value appropriately. He rest of your code should call the wrapper function and not the actual one.

Comment: @PeteBecker I suspect the OP isn't the least bit interested in being the *caller* of this function; rather I suspect they want to alter the result out from under the call without the caller knowing they did so. E.g.  the kind of thing [detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) does.

Comment: @PeteBecker basically because that function gets called inside the dll. So if i change that return value i could "hack" the whole dll system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter a function or the return of a function at runtime through hooking. There's several different techniques of hooking a function. The most common is called hot patching which in x86 overwrites the first five bytes of a function with a relative jump instruction to the middleware function. The middleware function can then choose to return to the caller or a piece of code called the trampoline. The trampoline restores the original replaced code and jumps back to the original hot patched function+5 to prevent a non terminating loop.

There's also IAT hooking but that's more of hooking API calls who resolve their address through the import address table located in the headers of the executable file format.

VMT is another form of hooking in which a virtual method can be hooked due to its address being replaced in the virtual method table. Similar to IAT but each instance of an object points to the virtual method table.

Have a look at this [book](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/windows-via-c-c-plus-plus-9780735639218) it's initially where I learnt about IAT and hot patching.

Comment: Also, John Robbins book on Debugging Windows is invaluable for this sort of thing.  That's where I first learned about all of th is

Comment: which is to say ,you need to write a driver with wdk which you have no chances to be signed by ms. good luck lady

Comment: You dont need any kernel priviledge to do this.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Usermode hotpatching can easily be bypassed yes especially in WOW64 since they all go through the same call gate to end virtualisation. But yes kernel mode drivers would be a sustainable hooking technique although those who do it most likely use exploits to bypass DSE.